# Angular 2 lazy loading module with external lib

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

How can i load external lib (e.g. ngx-leaflet) only in lazy load module moment (by click on according button)?

I did like this:

app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'gis',
    loadChildren: 'app/gis/gis.module#GisModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}];
```

gis.module.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// components
import { GisControllerComponent } from './controller/gis.controller.component';

// modules
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { LeafletMarkerClusterModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster';
import { LeafletDrawModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw';

// routing
import { routing } from './gis.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    routing,
    LeafletModule.forRoot(),
    LeafletDrawModule.forRoot(),
    LeafletMarkerClusterModule
  ],
  declarations: [GisControllerComponent],
  exports: [GisControllerComponent]
})

export class GisModule {}
```

gis.controller.component.html

```
<div #MapContainer id="MapContainer">
  <div leaflet id="LeafletMap"
       leafletDraw
       [leafletOptions]="options"
       [leafletDrawOptions]="drawOptions"
       (leafletMarkerClusterReady)="markerClusterReady($event)"
       (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

But when i use structure like this i'm getting error that i can't use any leaflet directives. However if i add import leaflet lib in app.module.ts it's working normally and there isn't errors.

I need to load libs only in load module moment. How can i do this?

Comment: are you using `leaflet directive` any where in app module as well?

Comment: Please share `gis.routing.ts` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake by myself. I used leaflet directive in 2 other components and it caused that error. Thanks for participating!